# Can't write JPEG files using Batik java.io.FilePermission PYCC.pf read

Tags: java, jpeg, batik

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1062

I'm running into the issue outlined in the Jira issue above.  Based on the comment from over a year ago, this issue seems to have been resolved.  I am not a Java developer, so I'm not sure what the response means, but I assume it's something that someone who contributes to the Batik project needs to integrate into the binary/release.

Since this was resolved back in December of 2013, I would assume it's integrated into the latest release of Batik, but it's not.  I'm running 1.7, and the issue still exists.  I'm wondering if anyone familiar with Java, or Batik, can help me with what I need to do in order to resolve the issue outlined above.

Comment: This ticket was closed with `Not a Problem`, so there is no "fixed" version.

Comment: @Tom So what does the comment from Dan mean?

Comment: That he found a fix for him. That doesn't mean that his way to fix that problem was included into the program.

Comment: @Tom Do you know what he's referring to?  I'm running into the same issue and I have no clue how to fix it, or what Dan's suggestion means.

Comment: It seems that he've added the 4 mentioned lines into this file: `/usr/lib/jvm/java/jre/lib/security/java.policy`.

Comment: @Tom And what if I don't have that file :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of investigation, I figured out how to solve this issue:

Create a java.policy file and tell java to use this policy file before executing batik.  The following code is all you need in the file:

```
 grant { permission java.security.AllPermission; };
```